# Yii2 - Combine Dynamic Form and Complex Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

**Dynamic Form Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Courses();
    $modelsCourseInstructors = [new CourseInstructors];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $modelsCourseInstructors = Model::createMultiple(CourseInstructors::classname());
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsCourseInstructors, Yii::$app->request->post());


        // validate all models
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsCourseInstructors) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    foreach ($modelsCourseInstructors as $modelCourseInstructors) {
                        $modelCourseInstructors->course_instructor_course_id = $model->course_id;
                        if (!($flag = $modelCourseInstructors->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->course_id]);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }
        // return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelsCourseInstructors' => (empty($modelsCourseInstructors)) ? [new CourseInstructors] : $modelsCourseInstructors
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have tried several methods but the code is not just working. 
Each work works independently, but combining the two is the issue that I am having.
What do I do to make it work. The second controller is shown below.

**Complex Form Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Courses();
    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        //The course was created successfully, so we can use its data to make course structure
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Courses'];
        $model->course_start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Courses']['course_start_date']));
        $model->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');

        $coursefile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'coursefile');
        if (!is_null($coursefile)) {

            //   if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->coursefile as $file) {
                //          $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);


                $model->course_file_name = $coursefile->name;
                $ext = end((explode(".", $coursefile->name)));
                // generate a unique file name to prevent duplicate filenames
                $model->course_file_path = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . ".{$ext}";
                // the path to save file, you can set an uploadPath
                // in Yii::$app->params (as used in example below)
                //$Photo = Yii::getAlias('@web').'/../data/ins_images/no-photo.png';
                Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/../web/data/course_admin_files/course_files/';
                // $model->course_file_path->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/data/course_admin_files/course_files/'.$model->course_file_path = 'Course_'.date("d-m-Y_His").'.'.$model->course_file_path->extension);
                //$model->course_file_path->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath.'/web/data/course_admin_files/course_files/'.$model->course_file_path = 'Course_'.date("d-m-Y_His").'.'.$model->course_file_path);
                $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->course_file_path;
                $file->saveAs($path);
            }//foreach

        }
        $model->save(false);

        if ($model->save(false)) //The course was created successfully, so we can use its data to make course structure
        {

            // check if topic format
            if ($model->course_format == Courses::TYPE_TOPIC) {
                //loop through and make the course structure with topic#
                // do your topic related stuff
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $model->course_format_no; $i++) {
                    $structure = new CourseStructure();
                    $structure->course_id = $model->course_id;
                    $structure->structure_name = $model->course_format . $i;
                    $structure->structure_id = $i;

                    // fill in other course structure data here
                    $structure->save();

                }
            }
            // check if weekly format
            if ($model->course_format == Courses::TYPE_WEEKLY) {

            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);


    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want create a form that will perform both functions.
**How do I combine the codes into One singular Controller **

Comment: what does not work ? what error or exception you get please provide proper information for  your question

Comment: Sorry for the inadequate information. No error or exception, but The save button does not respond. That's why I want to know how to combine these two controllers as one

Comment: i think you misunderstanding the mvc concept. you dont have to call a controller in a controller. use the controller to call a route, render a view with a form and do necessary workload in the model. in the first place, for a complex form the controller must not be necessary complex.

Comment: Thanks problem solved